# How to resolve org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientState.checkForActivity issue of mqtt client?

Tags: java, mqtt, mosquitto, broker

I have written mqtt client in java for mosquitto broker . it works for while but after sometime if there is no traffic between my client and mqtt broker it gets disconnected with following error:

**org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientState.checkForActivity : Timed out as no activity, keepAlive=30,000 lastOutboundActivity=1,493,194,287,903 lastInboundActivity=1,493,194,270,964 time=1,493,194,317,903 lastPing=1,493,194,287,903**

How do i stay connected to mqtt broker continuously?
what configuration settings do i need to make ?

### My current configuration of mqtt client are (following is just a snippet):

```
final String brokerUrl = AppProperties.getProperty(AppConstants.MQTT_BROKER);
final String clientId = "";
final String topic = AppProperties.getProperty(AppConstants.MQTT_TOPIC);
          MemoryPersistence persistence = new MemoryPersistence();

try {

      MqttClient sampleClient = new MqttClient(brokerUrl, clientId, persistence);
            MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
            connOpts.setCleanSession(true);
            if(!sampleClient.isConnected()){
                sampleClient.connect(connOpts);
            }
            LOGGER.info("Mqtt Connected to broker: "+ brokerUrl);

            sampleClient.setCallback(this);
            sampleClient.subscribe(topic);

            LOGGER.info("Subscribed");
            LOGGER.info("Listening");

        }
```

On Broker in the logs i am getting following error :

**1493181236: Socket error on client , disconnecting.**

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Is the clock changing on the device you are running this code on?

Comment: @hardillb you mean system clock? Yes .client is in the tomcat project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After trying many different parameters, the following parameters is stable for me. Hope it helps.

```
    final MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
    connOpts.setCleanSession(true);
    connOpts.setUserName(userName);
    connOpts.setPassword(passWord.toCharArray());
    connOpts.setConnectionTimeout(60); // This value, measured in seconds, defines the maximum time interval the client will wait for the network connection to the MQTT server to be established
    connOpts.setKeepAliveInterval(30); // This value, measured in seconds, defines the maximum time interval between messages sent or received
    connOpts.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
```